# Mapping software for Acer Aspire One netbook

Tags: google-maps

I want some suggestions for Windows Xp software. I travel a lot and do not have Google maps all the time. i want an offline mapping app like [TomTom maps](http://www.tomtom.com/products/maps/select.php) on my ultra portable netbook.

Comment: although i prefer Garmin, what's wrong with TomTom Maps?

Comment: I'm not sure, TomTom is for PDA/smart devices - http://www.tomtom.com/products/index.php?Lid=1 . do they have products for a computer ( on Windows Xp )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers/offered **MapPoint** and **Streets&Trips**. Both for offline mapping apps suitable for planning driving routes. You should check how much disk space they require on your machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/default.aspx?refcd=go002219s_map_point_2009

http://www.microsoft.com/Streets/en-us/default.aspx